# How to cancel Accordion.SelectionChanged on code behind?

Tags: silverlight, accordion

I'm using the silverlight toolkit Accordion control.

I want to cancel an accordion selection based on some logic.

For example:

```
private void Accordion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(Something) {
        e.SelectedItem = -1; //or anything that cancels the accordion "expansion"
        return;
    }
}
```

This code results in infinity calls to Accordion_SelectionChanged, even though the first recursive call do not affect the selected item.

Any other way to do this?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually prevent the recursive calls as follow:

```
bool isCancellingSelection = false;

private void Accordion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (isCancellingSelection)
        return;

    if(Something) {
        isCancellingSelection = true;
        e.SelectedItem = -1; 
        isCancellingSelection = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same thing as the function "Something" returning false the second time. For some reason the Accordion_SelectionChanged keeps being called over and over :(